# How to avoid iterate over dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe (example):

```
                                  time       t2m  ...        av      kont
latitude longitude                                ...                    
46.5     18.0      1998-01-12 07:00:00  0.284698  ...  0.001613          
         18.0      1998-01-24 08:00:00 -1.304504  ...  0.001418  FROMHERE
         18.0      1998-01-24 09:00:00 -1.113770  ...  0.002679          
         18.0      1998-01-24 17:00:00  0.345001  ...  0.004633  FROMHERE
         18.0      1998-01-24 18:00:00 -0.122498  ...  0.004400          
         18.0      1998-01-24 19:00:00  0.041565  ...  0.002184          
         18.0      1998-01-24 20:00:00  0.100861  ...  0.002220          
         18.0      1998-01-24 21:00:00  0.120636  ...  0.003083          
         18.0      1998-01-24 22:00:00 -0.615662  ...  0.004330          
         18.0      1998-01-24 23:00:00 -0.686798  ...  0.002404          
         18.0      1998-01-25 00:00:00 -0.743134  ...  0.000953          
         18.0      1998-01-29 02:00:00 -4.786346  ...  0.002984  FROMHERE
```

I need to perform function over each row and put result in additional column.

Example function:

```
def f1(t2m,av,d):
    return t2m*av+d
```

Important to note is that new value from previous row is input for current row. `d0` is known and `d` needs to be restarted to it on each occurence of `FROMWHERE`.

Desired output is:

```
                                  time       t2m  ...        av      kont   d
latitude longitude                                ...                    
46.5     18.0      1998-01-12 07:00:00  0.284698  ...  0.001613             d0
         18.0      1998-01-24 08:00:00 -1.304504  ...  0.001418  FROMHERE   d0
         18.0      1998-01-24 09:00:00 -1.113770  ...  0.002679             d[previous]+f1(t2m,av,d[previous])
         18.0      1998-01-24 17:00:00  0.345001  ...  0.004633  FROMHERE   d0
         18.0      1998-01-24 18:00:00 -0.122498  ...  0.004400             d[previous]+f1(t2m,av,d[previous])
         18.0      1998-01-24 19:00:00  0.041565  ...  0.002184             d[previous]+f1(t2m,av,d[previous])
         18.0      1998-01-24 20:00:00  0.100861  ...  0.002220             ...
         18.0      1998-01-24 21:00:00  0.120636  ...  0.003083          
         18.0      1998-01-24 22:00:00 -0.615662  ...  0.004330          
         18.0      1998-01-24 23:00:00 -0.686798  ...  0.002404          
         18.0      1998-01-25 00:00:00 -0.743134  ...  0.000953          
         18.0      1998-01-29 02:00:00 -4.786346  ...  0.002984  FROMHERE   d0
```

Any help in achieving this without looping dataframe is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the following function:

```
def f2(row):
    if row.kont == 'FROMHERE':
        f2.prevD0 = d0
    f2.prevD0 = f1(row.t2m, row.av, f2.prevD0)
    return f2.prevD0
```

Then, assuming that you have the appropriate value in *d0*,
apply this function the following way, saving the result in a new column:

```
f2.prevD0 = d0
df['d'] = df.apply(f2, axis=1)
```